# Build up SCORM functionality in PHP website

Tags: php, moodle, scorm, chamilo-lms

I have kept seeking any possible solution for a couple of days without any clue. It's really a pain to dealing with all the "***ANSWERS***" end by no meaning.

Hope anyone can help or at least point a right direction for me, I will be appreciated for that.

We are currently looking for open source solution to build **SCORM** functionalities which may include

1. Importing and rendering a **SCORM** course content
2. Exporting and modifying a **SCORM** course content
3. It's better to come with **Authoring** tools but not mandatory.

It seems `Moodle` and `Chamilo` have all the function we need, but they're all independent website, any possible just integrate their **SCORM** and Authoring functionality.

*Should satisfy SCORM 2004 standard*

Comment: Please note that searching for a specific tool or framework is considered offtopic on StackOverflow. Please ask your question on [http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @ventiseis

Comment: Also note what you're asking for is huge. It takes a team of developers months to create SCORM 2004 support (and many never quite get out the bugs) and you want it free.